# Real part of $\sqrt{ai-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Is there a way to find the real and imaginary parts of
$$
z=\sqrt{ai-1},\qquad a>0
$$
where $i=\sqrt{-1}$.  Thanks.  I do not know what to to do.
Note
$$
i=e^{i\pi/2}=\cos \frac{\pi}{2}+i\sin \frac{\pi}{2}.
$$

Comment: Convert $ai-1$ to polar form, and take the square root of the modulus and half of the argument?

Comment: how is it converted to polar form? Thank you @peterwhy

Comment: To polar form, you have to solve
$$ai-1 = r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)\\
a = r\sin\theta,\quad -1 = r\cos \theta$$
with constraint that $r \ge 0$.

Comment: @peterwhy Thanks, what do I do from here?  Sorry not familiar with this at all.  I have 
$$
a=-\tan \theta
$$
and 
$$
r=-1/\cos \theta.
$$

Comment: There is also a non-polar solution.consider $$\sqrt{ai-1} = bi+c$$ ...

Comment: @JohnJoy How can we use that to find the real and imaginary part though?  Can you post this please?  If not thank you anyways!

Comment: @Integrals $\theta$ can be solved by your first equation, mind the quadrant of $\theta$. The standard way of solving the modulus $r$ is by considering $(r\sin\theta)^2  + (r\cos\theta)^2$.

Comment: @peterwhy okay i still don't understand how to do so.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Integrals $ai-1 = (bi+c)^2 = c^2-b^2+2bci \implies c^2-b^2 = -1\text{ and } 2bc = a (\text{ or }4b^2c^2=a^2)$, use this information to solve for $b$ and $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for $z=x+iy$ you can right its Polar Representation $z=re^{i\theta‎}=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)=\color{red}{r\cos\theta}+i\color{blue}{r\sin\theta}$(respectively real part and imaginary part red and blue) where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta=tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x} $ for $x>0$ and $\theta=tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x}+\pi $ for $x<0$.

For $w = \rho e^{i \phi}$ that $w^n = z$,   $\rho = r^{1/n}$, $\phi = \frac{\theta}{n} + \frac{2\pi k}{n}$ for $k=0, 1, ..,n-1$.

here for $z=ai-1$, we have $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{(-1)^2+a^2}$ and $\theta=tan^{-1}\frac{a}{-1}+\pi $
thus answers will be $w=({a^2+1})^\frac{1}{4}e^{i(\frac{\theta}{2} + \frac{2\pi k}{2})}$(use method in used in red and blue part you will have)
real part first answer is $({a^2+1})^\frac{1}{4}cos\frac{\alpha}{2}$ and imaginary part is $({a^2+1})^\frac{1}{4}sin\frac{\alpha}{2}$ where $\alpha=tan^{-1}(-a)+\pi$ and...

Comment: my mistake, you are quite right.

Comment: I do not understand what you did, sorry.  First you wrote $z=re^{i\theta}$, then $\sqrt r e^{\frac{2k\pi+\theta}{2}}$, $k=0,1$ ,is this correct, are you missing an $i$ ?  what is this used for?  Thanks.  How did you get the real part ?

Comment: Can I see a full solution?  The answer has now changed three times.  Thanks.

Comment: let me write it with details @Integrals

Comment: @RaziehNoori  Okay, after i'll gladly check it off as the answer I am still just not really understanding your work.  Thanks!

Comment: i did it, hope this time it be use ful. @Integrals

Answer (score 2):

Convert $ai-1$ into polar form. Let $ai-1 = r(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)$. Then 
$$\begin{align*}
a &= r\sin\theta\\-1 &= r\cos\theta\\
r^2 &= (r\sin\theta)^2 + (r\cos\theta)^2\\
&= a^2 + 1\\
r &= \sqrt{a^2 + 1}\\
\tan \theta &= \frac{r\sin\theta}{r\cos\theta}\\
&= -a\\
\theta &= \pi - \tan^{-1} a
\end{align*}$$
Let $r(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta) = [p(\cos\phi + i\sin\phi)]^2 = p^2(\cos2\phi + i\sin2\phi)$ for $p\ge 0$.

Then $p^2 = r$ and $p = \sqrt r$. Also, there are two arguments $\phi\in[0,2\pi)$ that will satisfy $2\phi\equiv \theta \pmod {2\pi}$:
$$\phi_1 = \frac\theta 2,\quad \phi_2 = \frac{\theta + 2\pi}2$$
So one of the roots is
$$\begin{align*}
p(\cos\phi_1 + i\sin\phi_1) &= \sqrt[4]{a^2+1}\left[\cos\frac{\pi-\tan^{-1}a}2 + i\sin\frac{\pi-\tan^{-1}a}2\right]\\
&= \sqrt[4]{a^2+1}\left[\sin\frac{\tan^{-1}a}2 + i\cos\frac{\tan^{-1}a}2\right]\\
\end{align*}$$
and the other root is
$$\begin{align*}
p(\cos\phi_2 + i\sin\phi_2) &= \sqrt[4]{a^2+1}\left[\cos\frac{3\pi-\tan^{-1}a}2 + i\sin\frac{3\pi-\tan^{-1}a}2\right]\\
&= \sqrt[4]{a^2+1}\left[-\sin\frac{\tan^{-1}a}2 - i\cos\frac{\tan^{-1}a}2\right]\\
\end{align*}$$
Simplify the nested inverse tangent in (co)sine using half-angle formulae.
$$\begin{align*}
\sin\frac{\tan^{-1} a}2 &= \operatorname{sgn} a \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\tan^{-1}a}2}\\
&= \operatorname{sgn} a\sqrt{\frac{1-\frac1{\sqrt{a^2+1}}}2}\\
&= \operatorname{sgn} a\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{a^2+1} - 1}{2\sqrt{a^2+1}}}\\
\cos\frac{\tan^{-1} a}2 &= \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\tan^{-1}a}2}\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{1+\frac1{\sqrt{a^2+1}}}2}\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{a^2+1} + 1}{2\sqrt{a^2+1}}}
\end{align*}$$
For this question, $\operatorname{sgn} a$ is always $1$.

Comment: Thank you!  I am using $r=\sqrt{a^2+1}$ and $\theta=\pi-\tan^{-1}a$.

Answer (score 1):

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1439857/need-help-with-intro-question-about-complex-polynomials/1440039#1440039), I developed the expression for the square root of a complex number in Cartesian Coordinates.  Using that expression for $z=ai-1$ gives

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{z^{1/2}=\pm \left(\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{1+a^2}-1}{2}}+ i \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{1+a^2}+1}{2}}\,\,\,\right)}$$

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful!

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.

Comment: That notation suggests that there are four solutions.

Comment: @AntonSherwood No.  Convention is to follow the top to top and the bottom to bottom. But, I will edit to avoid confusion.  Thank you.

Comment: @Dr.MV This answer is very useful since you also referenced your other answer.  Thanks!  I will be posting a question on a differential equation today and I might put it as a bounty.  You'll see shortly.  Thank you.