# Find $\sqrt{8+6i}$ in the form of $a+bi$

Tags: complex-numbers

I need help with changing $\sqrt{8+6i}$ into complex number standard form.
I know the basics of complex number such as the value of $i$ and $i^2$, equality of complex number, conjugate and rationalizing method. This is my first encounter with such term and its only been a week since I learn about complex number. I would very appreciate a thorough explanation or just a calculation would suffice

Edit- Thank you guys, I've found both answer. And about the methods that Im not familiar with, It'll probably make sense to me after the next few class. I'll make sure to come back here and study them. Thanks again! You guys are great :D

Comment: Write out $(a+bi)^2=8+6i$ and see what values of $a,b$ are solutions.  Hint:  you should get two equations with two unknowns.

Comment: Do I expand (a+bi)²? Sorry, Im kinda bad at this

Comment: Yes, you would expand $(a+bi)^2$.  Hint: separate real and imaginary parts.

Comment: I got a²-b²=8 and 2ab=6, is this correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Yes.  That is *absolutely* correct!  There will be two sets of answers because it is a quadratic.

Comment: As a complete sidenote observe if (a + bi) is an answer the other answer will be -(a+bi) = -a - bi so it's nice to know that (-x)^2 = x^2 is true for complex numbers just as it is true for real numbers.

Comment: I see.. So this term has 2 standard forms right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "standard forms" but there should be two answers a + bi and a' + b'i where in both of them a^2 - b^2 = a'^2 - b'^2 = 8 and $2ab = 2a'b' = 6.  So I think you are correct.

Answer (score 3):

Elaborating slightly on Dr. MV's alternate approach:

We have

$$
8+6i = (a+bi)^2 = (a^2-b^2)+2abi
$$

where $a$ and $b$ are both reals.  Thus,

$$
a^2-b^2 = 8
$$

and

$$
2ab = 6
$$

From the second equation, we can write $ab = 3$, and therefore

$$
b = \frac{3}{a}
$$

If we substitute this into the first equation, we get

$$
a^2 - \frac{9}{a^2} = 8
$$

or, after multiplying both sides by $a^2$ and letting $u = a^2$, we have

$$
u^2-8u-9 = 0
$$

which is an ordinary quadratic equation that can be solved using the quadratic formula, or by simple factoring into $(u+1)(u-9) = 0$.  Remember, however, that as $u = a^2$, it cannot be negative, so we must discard the solution $u = -1$, leaving $u = a^2 = 9$, or $a = \pm 3$.  That leaves $b = \pm 1$ (that is, it is negative whenever $a$ is negative, and positive whenever $a$ is positive).

ETA: Fixed the sign of $b$.  Don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 2):

**METHODOLOGY $1$:  Using Polar Coordinate Conversion**

> In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1439857/need-help-with-intro-question-about-complex-polynomials/1440039#1440039), I used polar coordinate conversion to show that the square root of a complex number can be expressed in rectangular form by
>
> $$\begin{align}
> \sqrt{x+iy}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x}{2}}\pm i\,\text{sgn}(y)\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x}{2}}\tag 1
> \end{align}$$

Simply use $x=8$ and $y=6$ in $(1)$ to arrive at

$$\sqrt{8+i6}=\pm (3+i)$$

---

**METHODOLOGY $2$:  Using Strictly Rectangular Coordinates**

As an alternative development, we denote $a+ib=\sqrt{x+iy}$.  Upon squaring, we find that

$$a^2-b^2=x \tag 2$$

and

$$2ab=y \tag 3$$

Solving $(2)$ and $(3)$ simultaneously, we find

$$\begin{align}
a&=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x}{2}}\\\\
b&=\pm \text{sgn}(y)\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x}{2}}
\end{align}$$

in agreement with $(1)$

Answer (score 1):

Try $3+i$ (Square it out using foil and $i^2=-1$). Note $-3-i$ also works.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**
$$8+6i = 10 \exp\left(i\arctan\frac{3}{4}\right)\tag{1} $$
$$ \arctan(x)=2\arctan y\quad\Longrightarrow\quad x = \frac{2y}{1-y^2} \tag{2}$$
and $(x,y)=\left(\frac{3}{4},-3\right)$ is a solution of $(2)$.

Comment: @Dr.MV: that is not surpring, since we are dealing with a square root. I was just pointing the OP towards the fact that $1-3i$ (or, better, $\pm(i+3)$) has something to do with the solutions he is looking for.

Comment: I doubt the op has learned the polar representation of complex numbers yet.  I'd be very surprised if the first line would make any sense to a student who only learned complex numbers existed a week ago.

Comment: @fleablood: it is not in my power to control what the OP knows or does not, but an alternative approach to solving $$ (a+bi)^2 = (a^2-b^2)+i(2ab) = 8+6i$$ might be interesting as a teaching opportunity, I think.

Comment: Um, it's within your power to provide an answer that is useful for the OP.   What the heck is the point of answering a question here if it *isn't* to help the OP.  No-one cares if *we* know how to solve this question.  The only thing that matters is the OP asked for help that he or she would understand.

Comment: @fleablood was right. But I'll come back to this for sure once I've learned more of this topic. Thank you very much

Comment: "Answers are for everybody."  This answer was the third one, it provides a useful approach, and it wasn't exclusionary about it.

Comment: @AfiqAfandi don't be put off.  In the weeks to come you will learn that the complex numbers, having 2 dimensions, have a geometric representation where a complex number has a "size" r = $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ -- its distance from 0, and an angle $\theta= \arccos (b/r)$ from the x axis.  It will turn out that a+bi = $r(\sin \theta + \cos \theta i)$ which may seem complicated but once we discover that $e^{\theta i} = \sin \theta + i\cos \theta$ (!!!!!)  this will actually become a very useful 2nd way to right complex numbers.

Comment: ""Answers are for everybody." This answer was the third one, it provides a useful approach, and it wasn't exclusionary about it."  -- fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

do you know DeMoivre's theorem?

If $z$ is a complex number in polar form $z = \rho (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$ then $z^n = \rho^n (\cos n\theta + i \sin n\theta)$

In this case:
$\rho = 10\\
\theta = \cos^{-1}\frac 45\\
n=\frac12\\
z = 10(\cos \cos^{-1} \frac 45 + i \sin \cos^{-1} \frac45)$

$\sqrt {z} = z^\frac12 = \sqrt{10}(\cos \frac12\cos^{-1} \frac 45 + i \sin \frac12\cos^{-1} \frac45) $

$\cos \frac12\cos^{-1} \frac 45 = \sqrt{\frac{1+0.8}{2}} = \sqrt{0.9} =\sqrt{\frac 9{10}} \\
\sin \frac12\cos^{-1} \frac 45 = \sqrt{\frac{1-0.8}{2}} = \sqrt{0.1} = \sqrt{\frac1{10}}$

$\sqrt {z} = $$\sqrt{10}(\sqrt{\frac 9{10}} + i \sqrt{\frac 1{10}})\\
3 + i$

Comment: I think DeMoivre's theorem is something the OP has yet to look forward to.

Comment: I've learned a bit about DeMoivre's theorem. Apparently it's not in my syllabus. One question, how did you get θ = cos−1 45?

Comment: Update - I understand on how to get θ, but is it necessary to have the θ in cos?

Answer (score 1):

$$
8+6i = \sqrt{8^2+6^2} \cdot (\cos\theta + i\sin\theta) = 10(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)
$$
where $\cos\theta = \dfrac 8 {\sqrt{8^2+6^2}} = \dfrac 8 {10} = \dfrac 4 5$ and $\sin\theta = \dfrac 6 {\sqrt{8^2+6^2}} = \dfrac 6 {10} = \dfrac 3 5$.

The square roots are
$$
\pm\sqrt{10} \left( \cos\frac\theta 2 + i \sin \frac\theta 2 \right).
$$
For the tangent half-angle formula we get
$$
\tan\frac \theta 2 = \frac{\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta} = \frac{3/5}{1+ 4/5} = \frac 3 {5+4} = \frac 3 9 = \frac 1 3.
$$
So $\cos\dfrac\theta2 = \sqrt{\dfrac 1 {1+\tan^2\frac\theta 2}} = \dfrac 3 {\sqrt{10}}$ and $\sin\dfrac\theta2 = \dfrac1{\sqrt{10}}$.

Thus the square roots are
$$
\pm\sqrt{10} \left( \frac 3 {\sqrt{10}} + i \frac 1 {\sqrt{10}} \right) = \pm(3+i).
$$

It's easy to check this by multiplying: $(3+i)^2 = 8 + 6i$.

Answer (score 0):

If $(a+bi)^2=8+6i$, then $a^2+b^2=|8+6i|=2\cdot|4+3i|=2\cdot 5$.

So, let's try $a+bi=zw$ with $|z|=2$ and $|w|=5$. These are easy to find: $z=1+i$, $w=2+i$. But $(1+i)(2+i)=-8-6i$, so we take instead $iz=-1+i$ and $iw=-1+2i$, which gives $a+bi=(iz)(iw)=(-1+i)(-1+2i)=-1-3i$.

Comment: Hey, no fair taking advantage of the tendency of textbook problems to come out nicely! :-)

Comment: @BrianTung, actually, I had unique factorization in $\mathbb Z[i]$ in mind.

Comment: Ahh, OK, fair enough!