# Homework quesiton: Find $p$ and $q$ so that $(p+qi)^2=3-4i.$

Tags: complex-numbers

I got as far as taking the square root of both sides, and I'm ashamed to say that I'm already stuck. Any pointers?

In regards to the comment, I got as far as $q^4+3q^2-4=0$ by equating the parts that had $i$ and the parts that didn't, aka $p^2-q^2=3$ and $2pqi=-4i.$

Comment: Have you tried expanding the left side and matching real/imaginary parts?

Comment: Hi @user170231! I made an edit in regards to your comment.

Comment: Can't you just do it by inspection? $p,q$ are integers with absolute value less than 3.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1816005/find-sqrt86i-in-the-form-of-abi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can take these equations you have derived and solve them for $p$ and $q$.  Starting from scratch,

$(p+qi)^2 = p^2 + 2pqi + (qi)^2 = p^2 - q^2 + 2pqi$

Hence we have $p^2 - q^2 = 3$ and $2pq = -4$.  Setting $q = \frac{-2}{p}$ and plugging this into the first equation, $p^2 - \left( \frac{-2}{p} \right)^2 = 3$, or $p^4 - 3p^2 - 4 = 0$.

This can be factored to give $(p^2 - 4)(p^2 + 1) = 0$.  There are no real solutions to $p^2 = -1$, so we must have $p^2 = 4$, or $p = \pm 2$.  Then $q = -2/p = \mp 1$.

Hence $p + qi \in \{ 2 - i, -2 + i \}$.

Comment: I think you mean $p^4+3p^2-4=0.$ :)

Comment: @Max I don't - I wrote my equation in terms of $p$, while yours is for $q$, hence the discrepancy.

Comment: Ah, I thought the $p$ was a $q$ for a second.

Answer (score 2):

If you know about De Moivre's theorem then the easiest solution would be to put the right-hand side into polar coordinates, take the square root using the theorem and then put it back into the form $a + bi$.

A [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) to the Wikipedia page that describes it, look under "roots of complex numbers"

Comment: I'll be sure to read up on it! Is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: Sure. Solve the nonlinear system of the two equations you have written with two unknowns.

Answer (score 2):

Post-expansion of the left hand side, you have a system of two nonlinear equations with two unknowns
$$\begin{cases}
p^2-q^2=3\\[1ex]
2pq=-4
\end{cases}$$
which can be solved via substitution of variables. Rewrite the first second equation as, say, $p=-\frac{2}{q}$ (with $q\neq0$). Then in the first equation, you have
$$\left(-\frac{2}{q}\right)^2-q^2=\frac{4}{q^2}-q^2=3\implies q^4+3q^2-4=0$$
which is quadratic in $q^2$. That is, you can set $r=q^2$ and rewrite your equation as
$$r^2+3r-4=0,$$
find the solution for $r$, undo the substitution, solve for $q$, back-substitute into the first equation of the system, and finally find $p$.

Comment: It's $p^2 - q^2 = 3$ instead.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

This can be computed by a very simple $ $ [Square Root Denesting Rule:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/816527/242)

**Simple Denesting Rule** $\rm\ \ \ \ \color{blue}{subtract\ out}\ \sqrt{norm}\:,\ \ then\ \  \color{brown}{divide\ out}\ \sqrt{trace} $

$\ 3-4 i\ $ has norm $= 25.\:$ $\rm\ \color{blue}{subtracting\ out}\,\ \sqrt{norm}\ = -5\,\ $ yields $\,\  8-4i\:$

with $\, {\rm\ \sqrt{trace}}\, =\, \sqrt{16}\, =\, 4.\ \ \ \rm \color{brown}{Dividing\ it\ out}\ $ of the above  yields $\,\ 2- i$

**Remark** $\ $ Many more worked examples are in [prior posts on this denesting rule.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+denesting+subtract+norm+trace)

Answer (score 0):

Taking squared absolute values on both sides of $(p+qi)^2=3-4i$, we get  $p^2+q^2=|p+qi|^2 = |(p+qi)^2| = 5$. So $p=\pm 1$ and $q=\pm 2$ may yield a solution. By inspection, $1-2i$ is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting way to think about this problem:

If you square the imaginary number $re^{i\theta}$, you get the imaginary number $r^2e^{i2\theta}$. Using the tangent half-angle formula, we see that $\tan\left(\frac{\tan^{-1}\left(-\frac{4}{3}\right)}{2}\right)=-\frac{1}{2}$. So, $p=-2q$. Since $|3-4i|=5$, $|p+qi|=\sqrt{5}$. We conclude that the only two possible solutions are $2-i$ and $-2+i$.