# How do I break $q=\sqrt{a+ib}$ into its real and imaginary parts?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, mathematical-physics

I am unsure on how to do so with I under the square root. I can do so by just simply squaring both sides but I am trying to do so without using this method (need q for part of an equation).

Comment: Try to write it using exponentials

Comment: **Hint:** Write the number under the square root in its polar form.

Comment: The square root of a complex number is not uniquely defined.  When you write $\sqrt{a+ib}$, what do you mean?  The usual interpretation is to interpret the square root in terms of the principle branch of the logarithm...

Comment: See [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1439857/need-help-with-intro-question-about-complex-polynomials/1440039#1440039), which provides a full development.  And see Method 2 of [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1816005/find-sqrt86i-in-the-form-of-abi/1816018#1816018), which circumvents the use of polar coordinates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Converting to polar coordinates may help:

$$q = \sqrt{a+ib} = \sqrt{re^{i\theta}} = \sqrt{r}e^{i\theta/2}$$

Use the conversions $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $\theta = \tan^{-1}(b/a)$. (For the angle, you'll need to take the quadrant of the point into account.)

Comment: It's not correct that $\theta = \tan^{-1}(b/a)$. This only works if $a>0$. Otherwise you will have to add/subtract $\pi$ (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation )

Comment: @Winther Hi Hans.  Perhaps John is interpreting $\arctan(b/a)$ as $\arctan2(b,a)$.

Comment: See [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1439857/need-help-with-intro-question-about-complex-polynomials/1440039#1440039), which provides a more precise development.  And see Method 2 of [THIS ONE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1816005/find-sqrt86i-in-the-form-of-abi/1816018#1816018), which circumvents using polar coordinates.

Comment: @Winther Thanks; I edited to make it clear that you have to pay attention to the quadrant.